# Date Conversion (Excel 2016) - Pivot Table

Tags: date, excel-2016

Does anyone have any idea's how i could convert a date format when referencing a date from a pivot table.

E.g. The pivot table date will show 2019-01-01 and i cant change the field setting the pivot table itself.

However, i would like to (if possible) reference that date in another cell - but some how have it covert to 01/01/2019.

If that makes sense...does anyone have any ideas how that could be done?

Example:

Pivot Results           Look Up Results
ID  Creation Date
1   2019-01-01      01/01/2019

Answer (score 0):

Presume you have a 2 column pivot table showing ID number on the first column and date in the second column. The dates are in YYYY-MM-DD **text** format.

Now you want to look up the date from the pivot table using ID number as the reference. One way of doing that is to use **VLOOKUP** as in my following solution. It will return the date in YYYY-MM-DD text format.

Next step is to use **DATEVALUE** to convert the date **from text format to date format**, which will return 1/1/2019.

If you specifically needs to show 0 in day and month such as **0**1/**0**1/2019, then you need to use **TEXT** function to specify the format to be **DD/MM/YYYY**.

The formula should look like:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(VLOOKUP(Result ID,Range within Pivot Table,2,0)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

[image: Solution]